# Unity - How to separate the children of a game object linearly?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The goal is to "expand" a given model so that each piece is view able individually to the user so that the user can interact with each object separately (w/o worrying about which object they are in fact manipulating).

So, how to dynamically separate a game objects children linearly?

Linear example:
[image: Linear example]

So in the example there is an empty game object, which is the parent of 3 objects: a cube, sphere, and capsule. As the object is composed currently, the user cannot see all of the children.

In the 'expansion' example, I take each of the children and separate them linearly on the same axis by dragging each manually along the same axis (x in this case). How would one do this dynamically?

First thought is to calculate number of children a game object has, and run a loop on the parent that will move each child an increasing distance depending on which child is being moved. Ex: child_1 moves 3 units along the x axis, child_2 moves 6 units, child_3 9 units, et cetera.

Is this the best way to go about this? First instinct says this won't work in all cases depending on the size an object takes up. One child object might be many times larger then another. If this is the case, would it be better to separate the object not by units, but by moving each child object outside of each others collision boundaries?

Comment: You can determine how tall each object approximately is by checking [`Collider.bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-bounds.html). With that information, it should be trivial to determine where you need to move the objects so they no longer overlap.

Comment: @Serlite Yes, collider.bounds was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Glad you were able to deduce a solution on your own with that hint! That's the best way to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c#
int numChildren = gameObject.transform.childCount;
for (int i = 0; i<numChildren; i++)
{
    for (int a = i+1; a<numChildren; a++)
    {
        while (gameObject.transform.GetChild(a).GetComponentInChildren<Collider>().bounds.Intersects
            (gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).GetComponentInChildren<Collider>().bounds))
        {
            // print
            Debug.Log("Bounds intersecting " + i + ":" + a);

            // moving
            gameObject.transform.GetChild(a).GetComponentInChildren<Transform>()
                .transform.Translate(Vector3.right * 1f, Space.World);
        }
    }
}
```

1 - Gets the number of child objects

2 - Uses a nested for loop to see if a child's bounds intersects with any other childs bounds.

Ex: A gameobject has 4 children, objects zero, one, two, and three. The nested loop will compare object zero (0) against object one (1), 0 against 2, 0:3, 1:2, 1:3, 2:3. In this way it compares each child's collider.bounds with every other child's to ensure none of the child objects are touching.

3 - If the objects are touching, it moves the one comparing until it is no longer intersecting the one it compared with. Ex: 0:1 moves object 1 until it is no longer colliding with object zero.

NOTE: *1f (in 'moving') should be adjusted to the desired gap of separation between objects.

**EDIT**:: code is not robust, error checking and handling are not implemented here.